# Searching for a word by giving url as a input from document in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing the query to get the result of a word from the specific query.  have written the below one, I am not sure, it is not giving the expected result.

I have taken the elasticsearch search queries as a reference to get the results.

```
GET index_xxxx/_search
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "url":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }},
        { "match": { "content": "All"   }},
        {"bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"url": ".*/why-drupal8/."}}
            ]
        }}
      ],
      "must_not": [{ "match": {"url": ".*/tag/drupal8/." }}
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

xxx -> Indicates the 'url' and content-> Indicates the keyword. 
The keyword needs to be searched in the content of the URL.

*Due to privacy, I am not disclosing the info and named as xxx*

Comment: what is url type? text? keyword?

Comment: If my answer worked you have to mark as answer my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
Get index_xxxx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "url": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "All"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "url": ".*/why-drupal8/."
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "url": ".*/tag/drupal8/."
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me when I used match_phrase_prefix, instead of match.